# error of building google or-tools on win7

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-7, scip, or-tools

I would like to install google-or-tools (https://code.google.com/p/or-tools/)  on win 7 so that I can call third party optimization solvers (scip http://scip.zib.de/ ) from vidsual studio 2013.

I am new to the or-tools.

I followed the instructions at https://developers.google.com/optimization/docs/installing#source_windows

But, when I ran "tools/make.exe third_party" in cygwin, I got an error:

```
  makefiles/Makefile.cpp.mk:1573: warning: ignoring old commands for target `lib/libbop.'

  cd dependencies/sources/gflags-2.1.1 && \
    -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
     -D BUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON \
     -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../../install \
     -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fPIC \
     .
      C:\cygwin\install\tmp\make91243.sh: line 1: -D: command not found
      E:\Google_or_tools\or-tools-master\tools\make.exe: *** [dependencies/install/bin/gflags_completions.sh] Error 127
```

I cannot find the file make91243.sh in C:\cygwin\install.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but note that or-tools does not support Cygwin at the moment (see [this](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/or-tools-discuss/Msulsi8yKiU/discussion) post). On Windows, you need to use Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the last release (v6.5) support Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 on windows, and doesn't support Visual Studio 2013.